# X is the geometric random variable with P(X=1) =p. What is the expectation and variance of X in terms of p?

Tags: probability

I am a bit confused as I have as a "definition" of the geometric distribution

### $P(X=k)= p(1-p)^k$,

so here do I just shift everything by 1 and let

### $P(X=k)= p(1-p)^{k-1}$

and then solve the E(X) and Var(X) normally assuming X=/=0? In which case I get $E(X)= 1-p$ 
And what is the significance of this difference?

Comment: I do not know. There are two definitions of the geometric. The most common is the number of **trials** until the first success. So possible values are $1,2,\dots$ and $\Pr(X=k)=p(1-p)^{k-1}$. The other is the number of **failures** until first success, possible values $0,1,\dots$ and $\Pr(X=k)=p(1-p)^k$. For neither version is the expectation $1-p$. They are respectively $1/p$ and $(1-p)/p$.

Comment: Why is the number of possible values different in the two examples you give? Surely they should both be 0,1,2....??

Comment: The number of **trials** until the first success is at least $1$, for we count the trial on which the success occurred. I think there is a description of both versions in the Wikipedia article on the geometric distribution. The version that starts at $1$ is more common in elementary courses. I do not know what version your question is referring to, but you can find out by looking up the definition of geometric in the book/notes this problem comes from.

Comment: Do you like to solution I proposed, or you would like to know something more?

Answer (score 1):

perhaps the ambiguity in the definition has arisen because using the number of fails before the first hit gives a slightly more natural p.g.f., viz:
$$
f(x) = p\sum_{k=0}^\infty (qx)^k = \frac{p}{1-qx}
$$
in this case the expected value is
$$
\mu_1 = f'(1) =\frac{pq}{(1-qx)^2}|_{x=1} = \frac{q}p
$$
in this case
$$
\mu_2 = f''(1)=\frac{2pq^2}{(1-qx)^3}|_{x=1} = \frac{2p^2}{q^2}
$$
so
$$
\sigma^2 = \mu_2-\mu_1^2 = \frac{p^2}{q^2}
$$

Answer (score 0):

The first definition is a more common definition.
$P(X=k)$ in this case means the probability that $k$ is the first success.

In the second definition $P(X=k)$ means the probability of $k$ fails before the first success.

Using the first definition, you calculate the expected value in the following way:
$$E(X)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kp(1-p)^{k-1}=p\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k(1-p)^{k-1}=p \cdot \frac{1}{(1-(1-p))^{2}}=\frac{1}{p}$$

Note that the step $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}k(1-p)^{k-1}=\frac{1}{(1-(1-p))^{2}}$ is done by term-by-term differentiation as:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(1-p)^{k}=\frac{1}{1-(1-p)}$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k(1-p)^{k-1}=\frac{1}{(1-(1-p))^{2}}$$

Comment: I have made a mistake at the beginning, now corrected it.